# In Safari, is there a way to use the keyboard to select and click links/buttons on web pages?

Tags: keyboard, safari

When I use Firefox, I can tab through buttons and other links on web pages and then use the space bar or enter key to "click" the link or button. Is that same feature available in Safari? I think it's something in the preferences in Firefox that lets you do this, but I don't see that option in Safari's prefs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option-tab seems to do the trick.